# Jsoup html display in webview not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, webview

I am working on an android app in android studio, the app pulls some data from amazon and displays it in a webview.

For some reason the webview remains blank, I have tested my code in a standard java project using eclipse. The Jsoup code is good and runs clean in eclipse but in android studio it also shows no errors with the exception of no webview.

Here is my Code

```
public class showdata extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView firstresault;
  public String amazonproduct;
    public Element productamazon;
    public class getres extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=841351100182").get();
                productamazon = doc.select("div#s-item-container").first();
                amazonproduct = productamazon.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            WebView wview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.amazon_product);
            wview.loadData( amazonproduct, "text/html", null);
            Log.i("amazonproduct", "Null or Not");
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_showdata);
        new getres();



    }



}
```

I am new to the android api so I am sure that it is something simple. All help is appreciated!

logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                                          Process: com.example.rober.shoppingappbarcode, PID: 11086
                                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
                                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.jsoup.nodes.Element.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                              at com.example.rober.shoppingappbarcode.showdata$getres.doInBackground(showdata.java:28)
                                                                                              at com.example.rober.shoppingappbarcode.showdata$getres.doInBackground(showdata.java:20)
                                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to execute your `AsyncTask` using [`execute()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...)) function call

```
new getres().execute();
```

---

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_showdata);
        new getres().execute();
        //           ^^^^^^^
    }
```

---

Try using this

```
productamazon = doc.getElementsByClass("s-item-container").first();
```

instead of this

```
productamazon = doc.select("div#s-item-container").first();
```

Comment: close, but my app crashes a few seconds after I launch with the fix you added

Comment: @Top-Bot there must be then some other issues , post the logcat error details at the end of your question

Comment: @Top-Bot this `doc.select("div#s-item-container").first();` is returning nothing ,mean `null` hence the exception

Comment: Thanks Pavneet! You Rock!

Comment: @Top-Bot thanks for the compliment , i am glad that i could help , happy coding